# Making one entity to have two association with other same entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entity "user" and "vehicle".

- In this user can be a owner or driver of vehicle
- If user is owner he will have one to many relation with vehicle that is    working fine
- But if user is driver he will have one to one relation with vehicle.

I am facing the problem how make two type association between two entity at the same time.
I am posting code below that may help

> UserTravelDO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usertraveldo")
public class UserTravelDO implements Serializable {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Id
    private int userid;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String hint;
    private String firstname;
    private String middlename;
    private String lastname;
    private Boolean status;

    @JoinColumn(name = "addressid")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AddressTravelDO address;

    @JoinColumn(name = "roleid")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private RoleMasterDO role;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<VehicleTravelDO> vehicle = new ArrayList<VehicleTravelDO>();

    //@JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="driver",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private VehicleTravelDO driverofvehicle;

    private java.sql.Date modificationdate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    private java.sql.Date creationdate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    private String createdby;
    private String modifiedby;

    //getters and setters are below

}
```

> VehicleTravelDO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
public class VehicleTravelDO implements Serializable {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Id
    private int vehicleid;
    private String vehicletype;
    private String vehiclenumber;
    private int totalseats;
    private int availableseats;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UserTravelDO user;

    //@JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UserTravelDO driver;

    //Getters and setters are below

 }
```

> After doing this foreign key are getting generated at user and vehicle table.When i insert a vehicle with a user(driver) vehicle id is not getting inserted at the user table but at vehicle table userid(driverid) is getting
>   inserted.

Comment: A bidirectional association must always have an owner and an inverse side. The inverse site is marked by the usage of the mappedBy attribute. Hibernate only considers the owner side. Check the user documentation to see a correct mapping of a bidirectional one-to-one association.

Comment: OneToOne(mappedBy="driver",fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private VehicleTravelDO driverofvehicle;     is this is a correct way to do???

Comment: Yes, it is. Why don't you test it? I would name the field "drivenVehicle" instead, though, since the field is a reference to a vehicle, and not to a driver.

Comment: Tested it then also I got some error..once again I will try. I have one question the way I am implementing mapping is correct??

Comment: It's correct provided it matches with what you intend to do, and with how the tables are defined. I can't help with "some error". You'll need to be more precise than that.

Comment: After implementing I will post the error .thank you for your response @JB Nizet

Comment: @JB Nizet I got the output as I needed  .Thank you for your suggestions..